# screenshot is not in proper size IOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, screenshot

[image][image]In my IOS App Code I am taking screenshot of UIimageView but when I take it it's not taken properly by following code.

```
func captureView() -> UIImage {
//        let rect: CGRect = self.imageView.bounds

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)//add this line

        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
```

I want the exect screen shot of the image in imageView because there are more images on it.
Kindly suggest me proper code for getting exact UIImageView Screenshot

Comment: I want the exect screen shot of the image in imageView because there are more images on it. Means show me  screen shots

Comment: It's simple imageView.. I want to take shot of that..

Comment: Just Imageview not total screen

Comment: Once try this  imageview.layer.renderInContext(context)

Comment: it's working perfact but I need the other images on this image View is not coming in screenshot

Comment: wait i am sharing snaps

Comment: Hope you will get the idea

Comment: another images are placed in different imageviews

Comment: Check the another imagview is the subview of Main Imageview

Comment: yes.. Of Course.. self.view.addSubview(imageViews!)

Comment: Once change it .! add the Main imageview & check it

Comment: I did it then my gesture recognizer stops working.. Which is set on the imageViews...

Comment: add userintraction enable = Yes for all imageviews

Comment: I added and If I am removing navigationbar it's coming perfect

Comment: Done.. I take one another View and Add all imageViews as Subview..

Comment: every thing working fine

Comment: another problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716144/taking-screenshot-of-uiimageview-i-need-only-image-ios

Answer (score 0):

How about you add `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` instead of `0.0` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)`

```
func captureView() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
            drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return img!
        }
```

Comment: what is draw ViewHierchyinRect()

Comment: Please check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)

Comment: I am Asking about your method..   drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

Comment: It's not my own method.