# Taking Screenshot of UIImageView I need only image IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, screenshot

In my IOS App I am taking screenshot of UIImageView. It's very perfect as shown in attachment Photo. But here, I have taken `UIImageView content mode` **aspect fit**  . I've used this code.

```
func captureView() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false,UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)//add this line

        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.backView.layer.renderInContext(context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
```

Simply I need the snapshot of Image, Not the ImageView. Help me into this.[image]

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6284498/790842) to get the exact size of the image, and supply that size to the code when you are making screenshot, though you will need to adjust the `frame.x` too.

Comment: Get the image of an image view, `imageView.image`

Comment: @zylenv not trying to make that kind of easy thing

Comment: i didn't get whats your problem ?

Comment: It's screenshot of whole imageView I need only Image as Screenshot

Comment: @JAck try the solution what I suggested it just you need to get the frame of shown image and supply the frame to take screenshot, it should work.

Comment: i've tried but the problem in getting x & y.  I got the size of that that is nice algorithm

Comment: `x = imageView.frame.size.width - calculatedSize.width;` `y=0;` this will give close calculation, try this.

Comment: hey .. This algo is not giving me perfect value in same example my imageview frame have 320 , 402 size and image (by this func) returns 302,576 size

Comment: @JAck have you solved your issue ? i am facing same issue can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
func captureView() -> UIImage() {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(YourimageView.frame.size)
    YourimageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil)
    return img
}
```

Comment: Nice Try But Not Working.. Same Result as Above